# How to Polyfill node core modules in webpack 5 using ionic capacitor angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor, webpack.config.js

i tried making a custom webpack.config.js nothing works. i losing my hair now. XD
does someone know what to do, this is an ionic capacitor angular project.

Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\arjan\OneDrive\Bureaublad\ionic_proj\wallet_helper\node_modules@solana\spl-typ

[image]